# On Demand Linux t2.micro Instance Hour

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm hosting several websites on AWS and got the charge of On Demand Linux t2.micro Instance Hour for 690hrs. I've totally no idea about when I asked for this on demand instance. Is it like my free tier instance has used up so it automatically cost the on demand instance?

Also another question is how can I know which website/ec2 instance actually cost me the on demand instance hour. I strongly believe that none of my website has large traffic.

Comment: You are billed based on the number of instances which you use and the time they are considered running. If you are running an instance 24/7 you may want to look at getting a reservation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about billing issues.

Answer (score 21):

Complete information about your billing in details you may receive on a page https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home

Also, check the following - have you launched one more t2.micro instance? You have possibility to use free t2.micro instance for 750 hours per month, it means that you may have only one non-stop working instance per month.

Please, check, maybe you have set up autoscaling group that launched one more instance for you and forgot to disable it?